# react-select dropdown menu not clicking with protractor

Tags: protractor, react-select

I am trying to write an automation script with protractor that will select an element from a react-select dropdown menu. However, when I select the dropdown menu element and use .click(), the menu doesn't open. It seems that the react-select dropdown isn't responding to the .click() call. Is there another method to call on the react-select dropdown that will click the menu and open it?

Code for the dropdown menu.

```
  <div className={ cx('select-container')} data-mr-ass='grey-info'>
    <Select
      classNamePrefix='info'
      components={{ 
        DropdownIndicator: () => <Icon className={ cx('icon-wrap') } iconName={iconNames.downArrow} />,
        Option: (props) =>  <div data-mr-ass='grey-info-options'> <components.Option  {...props}/></div> }}
      isSearchable={false}
      onChange={selectGrayPercent}
      options={grayOptions}
      placeholder='Select'
      value={grayValue}
      openMenuOnClick={true}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried doing `$(attr('grey-info')).click();` but the menu doesn't open so I am unable to select any of the options in the menu. data-mr is my div class name to select elements using Protractor.

Comment: try to inject a script to do javascript click, let me know if you have difficulties

Comment: Could you also add your script ?

Answer (score 0):

you can now use [protractor-react-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-react-selector) to identify web elements by react's component, props, and state.

You can identify your target element by:

```
const myElement = element(
    by.react('Select', { someBooleanProp: true }, { someBooleanState: true })
);
```

Let me know if this helps!